# Jest/Enzyme | ComponentDidMount doesn't get called when it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a componentDidMount that executes the `fetchUser()`. I am trying to test that `componentDidMount`.

**The Component Code:**

```
static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.shape({
      isExact: PropTypes.bool,
      params: PropTypes.object,
      path: PropTypes.string,
      url: PropTypes.string
    }),
    label: PropTypes.string,
    actualValue: PropTypes.string,
    callBack: PropTypes.func
  };

  state = {
    user: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUser();
  }

  getUserUsername = () => {
    const { match } = this.props;
    const { params } = match;
    return params.username;
  };

  fetchUser = () => {
    getUser(this.getUserUsername()).then(username => {
      this.setState({
        user: username.data
      });
    });
  };
```

**The Test:**

```
    it('should call fetchUsers function only once', () => {
      const match = { params: { username: 'testUser' }, isExact: true, path: '', url: '' };
      const fetchUserFn = jest.fn(match);
      const wrapper = shallow(<UserDetailsScreen match={match} fetchUsers={fetchUserFn} />);
      wrapper.instance().componentDidMount(match);
      expect(fetchUserFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // I get expected 1 and got 0
    });
```

I mean why is this `componentDidMount()`, testing different than my other ones? I have tested quite a few of them over the past few weeks, never this issue. Maybe because the `getUser()` is a promise and I need to mock it. Has anyone stumpled on something like this before?

The code for the `getUser()`

```
export const getUser = username => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.GET_USER(username)
  };
  return instance(options);
};
```

Comment: I will post the whole component, but if I print with wrapper.debug(), I can see the whole component being rendered, and in other tests in which I check for specific data being populated, those test pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, by using `spyOn()`, by jest. Not sure why, I needed to spy for this particular use-case but please explain if you can. The solution below:

```
    it('should call fetchUsers function only once', () => {
      const match = { params: { username: 'testUser' }, isExact: true, path: '', url: '' };
      const fetchUserFn = jest.fn(match);
      const spy = jest.spyOn(UserDetailsScreen.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
      const wrapper = shallow(<UserDetailsScreen match={match} fetchUsers={fetchUserFn} />, {
        disableLifecycleMethods: true
      });
      wrapper.instance().componentDidMount(match);
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

One caveat here. If you do not user `disableLifecycleMethods`, the function will be called twice. Once for every render if I am not mistaken.